# In a responsive website (using bootstrap), how to center an anchor tag containing an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The following is not an option

```
<div class="container">    
<a href="/Home">
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/home_logo.png" alt="Home"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Cause the entire row (container) is now clickable and not just the home_logo.png

Is there any graceful way (maybe a bootstrap class) to make only the image clickable (and also for the image to be responsive).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you may to see, that you have two elements with `display: block` behavior (classes `.container`, `center-block` and `img-responsive` have `display: block` property) and one element with `display: inline` behavior (tag's `<a>` default behavior). You need to change `display: inline`  to `display: inline-block`. Simple solution to center nesting elements is to add to parent element (`div.container` in this case) one more Bootstrap's class `.text-center`. Class `.center-block` is extra and you may to remove it.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <a class="inline_block" href="/Home">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/home_logo.png" alt="Home">
  </a>
</div>
```

```
.inline_block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/kyyhc4oL/)

Comment: The problem is that the image is no longer responsive (when you make the a tag inline-block). So it will not resize automatically as you decrease/increase the size of your website. I guess you can use media queries... But that defeats using the img-responsive class!
Do you see any other way around using media queries?

Comment: @Sha Par, what do you mean? why the image no responsive now? I've put bigger image into previous code and created new example:  [jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/kyyhc4oL/1/)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <a href="/Home" class="inline_block">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/janosch500/tropical-waters-folders/512/Burn-icon.png" alt="Home">
  </a>
</div>
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyyhc4oL/5/)

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 5** you can use align-items utilities on flexbox containers to change the alignment of flex items on the cross axis (the y-axis to start, x-axis if flex-direction: column).

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <a href="/some"><img src="/images/jack.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Check docs link - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#align-items